how to compare size of exponents by using log 10?
Can someone tell me how I can answer the following question:

Bring the following numbers $a=1000^{1000}$, $b=1005^{999}$,
$c=1015^{998}$ and $d=1025^{997}$ in the right order by using
$\log10$.

I can convert $1000^{1000}$ into $\left(10^3\right)^{1000}$ so it is $10^{3000}$ but what about the other ones? Or is it the wrong approach?
Thanks in advance.

Not sure if you've been taught the trick to do this. You can use the identity:
$$a^b = \left(10^{\log_{10}(a)}\right)^b = 10^\left(\log_{10}(a)\cdot b\right)$$

Are you allowed to use a calculator with a logarithm key or logarithm tables?

Exponentiation is normally considered right-associative so $10^{3^{1000}}$ means $10^{(3^{1000})}$, a number than is not equal to either of the numbers you're considering.

thanks for you comments. When I put it in the calculator it gives me an error. I guess since numbers are pretty big. My problem is to turn 1005^999 as well as 1015^998 and 1025^997 into something where the basis is 10. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks

I did not learn the trick Daniel wrote so not sure if I am supposed to use it. Is there another way?

I did not learn the trick Daniel wrote --- Here's a well-known method that probably many people discover themselves when in school. Rewrite each as a power of $10$ using base-$10$ logarithms. For example, write $1005^{999} = {10}^x,$ take base-$10$ logarithms of both sides to get $\log({1005}^{999}) = x,$ and hence $x=999\cdot\log 1005,$ which CAN be evaluated easily if you are allowed to use a calculator (something you never answered when I earlier asked). Since $f(x) = 10^x$ is a strictly increasing function, the order of the numbers will be the same as the order of the exponents of $10.$

These numbers when evaluated are all very close to each other. This isn't a problem where loose approximations will be of any use. Thus, I have to assume you are expected to use a calculator. To say the same thing as Dave Renfro, but more simply: Calculate the $\log_{10}$ of each value (exponent times log of the base). Because exponentiation and logarithms are increasing functions, the order of the original values is the same as the order of their logarithms.

Welcome to MSE! <> In addition to addressing Dave's and Paul's comments about available tools (calculator and/or log table), it would help if you'd edit the question to say where this question arises. Are you taking calculus? Multivariable calculus? Just asking curious questions about large numbers? Learning logarithms for the first time?

When someone edits your question and deletes a necessary pair of parentheses while doing so, you're allowed to edit the question again to put them back. Likewise, if you did not actually want those parentheses then you can undo the edit I just made, but I hope you really did want them because without them the formula is not correct (as previously noted in another comment).

Thanks heaps for all your answers. That makes perfect sense now. Yes I can use a calculator. Sorry for not answering to that question beforehand. It is high-school math I am dealing with here. I understand now how to do it. Thanks a lot for all your help :-)
